# database driven webservice using axis

Tags: java, database, web-services, axis

I would like to create a database driven webservice (only to retrieve data)

so I want to know where to start ? (POJO or EJB)

is it better to make individual functions for each query?

Comment: Perhaps a Google search for "create web service using axis" is in order here.

Answer (score 0):

Use WSO2 DSS[1]. This is a product specifically created for such purposes.

[1] http://wso2.org/library/dss